# There is no web app deployed when I create a Azure bot?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service

I follow with this document:[Register a bot with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned).

When I went to the second step, I found a problem.
[image]

[image]
There is no web app in the source group.And I can not find any item about this at the app services page.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a bot service and integrate it with the SharePoint framework. @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: You should have resource group. Then have to go to `Azure Bot` it  will lead you to `bot registration page` here need to fillout the page then your bot would be register but still it can do anything unless you `register the app service` for it. Once you  `register the app service` then need to update `Messaging endpoint` from your `app service url` under `Configuration` on your bot page. Now you have to `deply your bot source file` on the app service you have created Then it will be functional means you can test chat or what you want. Feel free share if you have any further concern.

Comment: did you able to made any progress? Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: There is no step to create an app service in the document. I thought there was a problem with my creation. Thank you！

Comment: Well, I am showing that for you, since the new version of `azure bot` released it doesn't create app service autometically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already shared that first we should have resource group to create `app service` and `azure bot registration`. Follow the steps below:

***`Resource group:`***

[image]

***`App Service:`***

Once you have created your `resource group` go `create resource` and search for `web app` See the screenshot below:

[image]

> Create the `web app service`. And this will be work as your bot
> `backend` service. If you see the below screenshot you can have a look
> `URL` which will be endpoint of your bot. Please copy it.

[image]

***`Azure Bot Registration:`***

Now go to `Create resource` once again and type `Azure Bot` create the bot. And then  go to the `configuration` like below:

[image]

> ***`Note:`*** You have copied the `web app service URL` last time. Paste that `URL` into the `Messaging endpoint` with adding
> `https://yourAppServiceURL.azurewebsites.net/api/messages` and check
> the `Enable Streaming Endpoint` and finally click on `apply` up to now
> we are done. But still our bot doesn't know anything what it will do
> since it has nothing at it's backend. Next steps we will publish our
> sample bot code on the `app service` we have created.

***`Deploy Bot Prject on app service:`***

From your `IDE` publish your bot source file. It would prompt you following page:

[image]

Select your `Resource group` and then select your `App service` then just finish.
It should be like below :

[image].

Now our `Bot` is good to work with.

***`Test On Web Chat:`***

Now go to your bot registration page and hit `Test in Web Chat` as you can see it as pro actively greeting me.

[image]

Hope above steps guided you accordingly.